# Android LocationManager in "Phone Only" mode

Tags: android, android-location

I am trying to use the following code snippet on an Android app with targetSdkVersion = 22. ([source](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html#Updates))

```
// Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

// Define a listener that responds to location updates
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
      // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
      System.out.println(location);
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
  };

// Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

In my manifest permissions, I have:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" />
```

Under Settings -> Location, my phone (Galaxy S8) has three locating methods:
`High accuracy`, `Battery Saving` and `Phone only`. This code successfully works for the first 2 locating methods but not `Phone only`.

`Phone only` says it "Uses GPS to estimate your location", so I would expect using the GPS_PROVIDER would be sufficient to get location changes.

Why isn't it working?